# How can I search for an unknown date and replace with a date of my chosing in VBScript?

Tags: replace, vbscript

I am trying to use this code to find an unknown date and replace it with my chosen date, but it keeps coming back with "calibration date \d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} was not found". I know that using RegEx will allow me to do this correctly, but I am not quite sure how to incorporate it into the existing code? I have not really worked with RegEx but I would be willing to try.  I am only really comfortable with ATLAS.

```
' This code replaces one string by another inside files looping though    
' subfolders.
' It is vbscript so copy the text below in a .txt file and rename to .vbs
' It will take any non zero bytes file except for extensions you filter 
' out in advance.

Option Explicit
Dim objFilesystem, objFolder, objFiles, objFile, tFile,  objShell,         
objLogFile,objFSO, objStartFolder, colFiles
Dim SubFolder, FileText, bolWriteLog, strLogName, strLogPath, strCount,
strCount2, strOldText, strNewText, strEXT 
bolWriteLog = True
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const TriStateUseDefault = -2
Set objFilesystem = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
strLogName = "dateX.txt"
strLogPath = "C:\Users\e344765\Desktop\Find and replace" & strLogName


strCount = 0
strCount2 = 0
strOldText="calibration date \d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}" 
strNewText="calibration date 01-17-2016"
strEXT = "exe,dll,ps"

ShowSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Sub  ReplaceText(objFile)

strCount = strCount + 1
    WriteLog("Opening " & objFile.Name)
    Set tFile = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TriStateUseDefault)
    FileText = tFile.ReadAll
    tFile.Close
    If   InStr(FileText, strOldText) Then
         WriteLog("Replacing " & strOldText & " with " & strNewText & ".")
         FileText = Replace(FileText, strOldText, strNewText)
            WriteLog("Text replaced")
    Else
            WriteLog(strOldText & " was not found in the file.")
            strCount2 = strCount2 +1
    End If
    Set tFile = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting, TriStateUseDefault)
    tFile.Write FileText
    tFile.Close
    FileText = ""
strCount = 0
strCount2 = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to [edit] the tags of your question to indicate which language that is.  And although you have included sample code, there looks to be a lot there that's not relevant to a focused question.  Pick one thing you're having a problem with and write a [mcve] for that.  You may also find some pearls of wisdom in the [ask] guide.

Comment: Does VBScript even support regular expressions? FileSystemObject does not in filenames.

Answer (score 0):

[Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954(v=vs.84).aspx) seeks fixed/literal strings; if you want to search for variable patterns you need a [RegExp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/ee236360(v=vs.84).aspx).

```
>> s = "calibration date 01-17-2016"
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "calibration date \d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}"
>> WScript.Echo InStr(s, r.Pattern)
>> WScript.Echo r.Replace(s, "abc")
>>
0
abc
>>
```